# How do mobile games store and retrieve unique user data

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'd like to know how some games such as LINE Bubble or whatever store user statistics and game data, ect.. I'm guessing it must be with php and sql or something like that, but can someone be a bit more specific? Since some of these games don't require direct input of usernames and don't use passwords how do they know the correct data to retrieve? Do they use the phone number or some sort of device id that the mobile os provides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each OS provides a unique identifier to the user, one way or the other.

To get a unique identifier for iPhone, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22937460/1891327

For android you can see this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/1891327