# Track Referral in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tracking, referrals

I wanted to track referral code shared on social media for ios app.
As `UDID` is not provided by apple. I have tried various approach to get it done but, none of the method works 100%.

1) I tried to track IP, Vendor ID and match it with installed App. But, When user installed app from one IP and signup from other IP address. It does not works well.

2) I played with [branch.io](http://branch.io) to track referrals. The problem with branch.io is, If i installed app with one Wi-Fi network and signup with other Wi-Fi network. I lose the referral tracking code. Below is sample call:

```
[Branch getInstance] initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && [params objectForKey:@"+clicked_branch_link"]) {
        NSLog(@"deep link data: %@", [params description]);
    }
}];
```

3) Thinking to store referral in cookie and access it via SDK. But as suggested by experts it is not an ethical to do this.

Can anybody suggest method to achieve this?

Comment: You can store the Vendor ID as approached in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606773/always-get-a-unique-device-id-in-ios-7